# VSCode busy/running indicator in-line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way to show what part of the code is running in Visual Studio Code (Python) ?

Exactly like the green arrow in Colab.
[Green indicator in Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7w6H.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As answere: Just debug your project. - But you will get answeres like this if you consult the manual...